# Vscode live server not working even after using local ip as host

Tags: frontend, localhost, vscode-extensions, liveserver

[image]

vscode live server is not working. I even clicked use local ip as host in the vscode live server extension settings

Comment: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. please revise your question and add more details and imagine if someone that has no clue about your situation and environment that wants to help you but all he/she will get is a vague but famous error page in a browser. good luck